# $\int^{\infty}_{0}x^{r +s- 1}(1 + x)^{-s}(1 + x^2)^{-\frac{rm}{2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, mathematica, gamma-function, maple

I'm trying to solve the integral

$\int^{\infty}_{0}x^{r +s- 1}(1 + x)^{-s}(1 + x^2)^{-\frac{rm}{2}}dx$,

where $s$, $r$ and $m$>1 are positive integers.

My question is whether a closed form solution for this integral exists. By closed form here I mean an expression in terms of a finite number of special functions. There is some hope for a closed form solution I think given the output below from symbolic software, but I have been unable to find a formula yet.

To give a bit of context the integral is the $s$-th moment of the real random variable $x/(1+x)$, $x>0$, when the probability density function of $x$ is, up to a constant that I have omitted for simplicity, is $x^{r - 1}(1 + x^2)^{-\frac{rm}{2}}$. All these moments should exist. I am trying to understand whether they are expressible in terms of a finite number of special functions.

I was not able to get help from Mathematica or Maple. Both Mathematica and Maple give me a solution containing a $\Gamma$ function evaluated at negative integers. More precisely, if I input in Mathematica

`Integrate[
 x^(r + s - 1) (1 + x)^-s (1 + x^2)^(-r m/2), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> {r \[Element] Integers, s \[Element] Integers, 
   m \[Element] Integers, r > 0, s > 0, m > 1}]`

I obtain

`(1/Gamma[s])
 Gamma[(-1 + m) r] Gamma[
   r - m r + s] HypergeometricPFQ[{(m r)/2, -(r/2) + (m r)/2, 
    1/2 - r/2 + (m r)/2}, {1/2 - r/2 + (m r)/2 - s/2, 
    1 - r/2 + (m r)/2 - s/2}, -1] + (1/(
 2 Gamma[(m r)/
   2]))(-s Gamma[1/2 (-1 + (-1 + m) r - s)] Gamma[
     1/2 (1 + r + s)] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 + s/2, 1 + s/2, 
      1/2 + r/2 + s/2}, {3/2, 3/2 + r/2 - (m r)/2 + s/2}, -1] + 
   Gamma[1/2 ((-1 + m) r - s)] Gamma[(r + s)/
     2] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 + s/2, r/2 + s/2, s/2}, {1/2, 
      1 + r/2 - (m r)/2 + s/2}, -1])`

which is:

$\frac{\Gamma(r(m-1))\Gamma(s-r(m-1))}{\Gamma(s)}  {}_{3}F_{2}\left(  \frac
{mr}{2},\frac{r(m-1)}{2},\frac{1+r(m-1)}{2};\frac{1-s+r(m-1)}{2},1+\frac
{s-r(m+1)}{2};-1\right)   -\frac{s\Gamma\left(\frac{r(m-1)-1-s}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(  \frac{1+r+s}{2}\right)  }
{2\Gamma(\frac{mr}{2})}{}_{3}F_{2}\left(  \frac{1+s}{2},1+\frac{s}{2}
,\frac{1+r+s}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3+s-r(m-1)}{2};-1\right)   +\Gamma\left(  \frac{r(m-1)-s}{2}\right)  \Gamma\left(  \frac{r+s}
{2}\right)  {}_{3}F_{2}\left(  \frac{1+s}{2},\frac{r+s}{2},\frac{s}{2}
;\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{s-r(m-1)}{2};-1\right)$

(same solution for Maple) As you can see, there is a $\Gamma$ function evaluated at $s-r(m-1)$ which can be a negative integer, so it seems to me that Mathematica and Maple are giving a solution that holds for most real values of $(r,m,s)$ but not necessarily for the values I'm interested in ($r,m,s$ are positive integers in my problem)

Comment: Please give $\LaTeX$ format to the solution. As you suspect, the $\Gamma$ function has poles at negative integers, and it's likely that both _MMA_ and _Maple_ either are ignoring that the arguments are integers, or there are other terms canceling the poles. It's hard to say without a properly formatted solution.

Comment: @Pragabhava Edited, thanks

Comment: If I input `Integrate[x^(r + s - 1) (1 + x)^-s (1 + x^2)^(-r m/2), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {r \[Element] Integers, s \[Element] Integers, m \[Element] Integers}]` to _MMA_, I get `ConditionalExpression[...,r < m r && r + s > 0]`. This means the solution is only valid when $r < m$ and $0 < r + s$. It's clear from the form of the original expression that the integral will not converge for all values of $m$, $r$ and $s$.

Comment: The condition in ConditionalExpression is $r < m r$ (not $r < m$) which is always satisfied because $r$ is a positive integer and $m$ is a positive integer larger than 1.

Comment: Why do you say that "it is clearer from the form of the original expression that the integral will not converge for all values of $m$, $r$ and $s$." I cannot see that.

Comment: First, you are right, the condition is $r < rm$ and not the way I wrote it (missed the r). Second, I didn't saw the restrictions $0<r$, $0<s$, $1<m$. With them, the integral exists everytime. I haven't been able to compute the formula, but it has everything to do with the [integral representation of $\,_3F_2$](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/07/01/01/).

Comment: You might have more luck getting an answer at MathOverflow.